# Representing collections data correctly in JSON after XSLT conversion from XML

Tags: arrays, json, xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT, which is converting XML data to JSON.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">{
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object or Element Property-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Array Element -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object Properties -->
<xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:call-template name="ctlchar">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>"</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>{
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
}</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Attribute Property -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(name(), 'xsi:'))">
        "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace carriage return with \n -->
<xsl:template name="ctlchar">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="." />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pText" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="substring-before($pText, '&#xD;')" />
            <xsl:text>\n</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="ctlchar">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText"
                    select="substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fairly well, but I have run into an issue.

This xml:

```
<items>
   <item></item>
   <item></item>
   <item></item>
   <item></item>
<items>
```

gets converted to this JSON:

```
"items" : {
   "item" : [
     {},
     {},
     {},
     {}
    ]
}
```

The items are all contained in an array, and this seems correct. However, the following XML:

```
<items>
   <item></item>
<items>
```

Gets converted into this:

```
"items" : {
   "item" : {}
}
```

This makes the JSON difficult to parse, since item is sometimes an array and sometimes an object.

This is an inherited project, I don't know how it started. I'm just trying to figure out if this is conventional? It seems like it should be an array of 1 if it is an array of 4.

I see the same XSLT posted around online as a solution for xml->json so I am confused. Not sure how to tell a client to parse this. I also don't know how to fix the xslt, since it seems like the xslt can't know whether or not a single-item collection should be an array or a single object.

Answer (score 1):

> I also don't know how to fix the xslt, since it seems like the xslt can't know whether or not a single-item collection should be an array or a single object.

That's the whole point here. Your XSLT must somehow know if you're dealing with a collection or a single item.

This is quite difficult to solve in general, but rather easy to solve for a specific case.
The condition in `<xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">` checks if you'll need an array or a single item. You may consider to modify this condition to work correctly for your specific case. That would be a bit of hardcoding, but it's probably the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. The issue I posted is actually simplified, and these documents contain lots of dynamic data so I don't see a good way to do this for specific cases. It just seems like this would be a common issue with a good known fix or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect way of converting XML to JSON, and every converter does it differently. The issue you have hit is one of the classic difficulties. If a book has a single author, there is no way of knowing whether other books might have multiple authors and therefore whether the author should be a single item or an array of length 1.

In my view the only way to do the conversion is with semantic knowledge. Both the XML and the JSON representation need to be derived from the underlying semantic data model, not from each other, and the conversion needs to be aware of the data model, which means that purely mechanical conversion is always going to produce unhappy results.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am currently considering a workaround where the xml is annotated with attributes to indicate collection elements. This way I think I could make a better xslt. Though I might still run into other problems.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @MichaelKay's answer...

If the XML document was validated against an XSD using a Java XML parser then it should be possible *in principle* to get the Post-Schema Validation Information (PSVI) for the element and get its xsd:maxOccurs value. Then, if maxOccurs = 1 you could output a single JSON field, else output an array.

However, I don't know of any tool that does this. Not sure why, but I suspect that it is not always possible to know for sure (*from the PSVI*) which XSD object a particular tag was matched against. Michael may be able to confirm/deny that theory.